# Why does Google Play say my app is incompatible with devices it should be working on?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-games

I recently published an app I was working on for practice (
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ali.ColorMatch2) and I asked my friend to test it out for me on his Nexus 5 running android 6.0.1. I also used a Nexus 5 to run the apk when I was developing the app. For some reason he got a message saying "This device is not compatible"

It's an extremely simple app that uses no features that should be limiting compatibility. The only thing I have to limit compatibility is a little chunk of code declaring it only compatible with handsets, but I copied that directly from https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ali.ColorMatch2">
<compatible-screens>
   <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />            
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    </manifest>
```

Google play takes several hours to update after you upload another apk, so it's hard for me to try out stuff and see if it works. I've looked at the other times similar questions have been posted and those solutions have not worked. My apk is not even 2 MB, so I know it's not because it's too large, and it only uses two features - android.hardware.FAKETOUCH and android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT

Here is the Google Play developer console run down on my apk: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAxqc.jpg

Thank you

*** EDIT ***

After adding xxhdpi definitions:

```
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
```

on the `compatible-screens` section, I am now getting a [warning on the Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsAOV.jpg) saying that my app is designed for tablets, and I don't want that, should I worry about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no xxhdpi screens supported in your list, so my guess is that somehow the screen configurations are different in those two phones. Either remove the section or add definitions for xxhdpi and larger screens:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

I think the warning is expected, since you are defining compatibility for large screens and dpi's.

Comment: I need to keep that to ensure it is not downloadable on tablets. I just looked it up and the Nexus 5 has a screen density of 445 ppi, and xxhdpi is 480 ppi, so you may be right. I'll add definitions for xxhdpi, thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Please take the time to contribute and upvote/mark my answer if it was useful to your question.

Comment: Hey so I very hastily made the change and re-uploaded my apk, and now google is telling me my app is designed for tablets? What? http://imgur.com/a/FqtrA

Comment: Done. Also, it the Play Store is still saying my new apk that has the definitions for xxhdpi screens is incompatible with the Nexus 5 and Galaxy S6.